# pagination Show no result when try go to page 2 (Result Filter By Name And Date)

Tags: php, mysqli, filter, phpmyadmin, pagination

When i Try TO GO To Page 2 i GOT Blank Page without Result
because The first Condition  `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`
in this Condition it's must select name & datefrom & dateto and submit to show result so when we go to page 2 and later this Condition  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` is not TRUE right ?

any idea to fix that i still thinking about away for that but i didn't find and my head will explosion :D

i take'd 3 day's trying to resolve it :(
and i tr'd to use all way that's appear in Stacoverflow but no one fix it

Here is my code and my DB For Help

***Edited***

**showbydrivers.php**

```html
<?php //session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="$1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
    <title>Under work</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!----- `drivers` ----->
<?php
require 'config.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `driversuser`";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query);
//

//
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="addingcar">
        <form dir="rtl" method="post">

            <div class="">
                <b>عرض وردية سائق</b>
            </div>

            <br/>
            <label>
                <b>اختر السائق</b>
                <select name="insdname" id="framework" class="align-right selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
                    <option style="text-align: right" value="">اختر السائق ...</option>
                    <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):; ?>
                        <option style="text-align: right" value="<?php echo $row1[10]; ?>"><?php echo $row1[1]; ?></option>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </select>
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
                <b>من</b>
                <input type="date" name="datefrom" required>
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
                <b>الي</b>
                <input type="date" name="dateto" required>
            </label>
            <br /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_framework" id="hidden_framework" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="عــــرض" />

        </form>


        <?php

        $divcon = '<div class="result-info" style="text-align: right; font-size: 17px; background-color: #ff661a; padding: 5px; margin-top: 5px;">';
        $num_rec_per_page = 3;
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            echo $divcon;
            $selected_val = $_POST['insdname'];
            $date_val = $_POST['datefrom'];
            $dateto_val = $_POST['dateto'];
            $totalprice = 0;
            $totalprice_paid = 0;
            ////////////////////

            if(isset($_GET['pg']))
            {
                $pg = $_GET['pg'];
            }
            else
            {
                $pg = 1;
            };
            $startfrom = ( $pg-1 ) * $num_rec_per_page;

            ////////////////////
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            $driverName = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `reports` r1 INNER JOIN `driversuser` d1 ON r1.DriverCode = d1.Driver_ID WHERE r1.DriverCode = '$selected_val'");

            while ($datareport2 = mysqli_fetch_array($driverName)) {
                echo "<div style='margin-top: 0px';>";
                echo "<div style='font-size: 18px; color: blue; display: inline';>اسم السائق: </div>";
                echo "<div style='display: inline';>".$datareport2['DriverName']."</div>";
                echo "<div style='display: inline; margin-right: 10%; color: white; border: dotted 2px yellow; padding: 2px;'>";
                echo "<div class='datefrom' style='display: inline; color: white;'>"."فاتوره من ";
                echo "<div style='display: inline; color: black; margin-right: 10px;'>".$date_val."</div>"."</div>";
                echo "<div class='dateto' style='display: inline; margin-right: 10px; color: white;'>"." الي ";
                echo "<div style='display: inline; color: black; margin-right: 10px;'>".$dateto_val."</div>"."</div>";
                echo "</div>"."</div>";
                break 1;
            }
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            /////////***********///////////
            $carinfo = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `reports` r1 INNER JOIN `cars` c1 ON r1.CarCode = c1.Car_ID INNER JOIN `driversuser` d1 ON r1.DriverCode = d1.Driver_ID WHERE r1.Datefrom BETWEEN '$date_val' AND '$dateto_val' AND DriverCode = '$selected_val' ORDER BY r1.Datefrom DESC LIMIT $startfrom , $num_rec_per_page");
            while ($carReport1 = mysqli_fetch_array($carinfo)) {

                echo '<div class="reportsrow" style="background-color: #006600; color: white; margin: 7px; padding-right: 8px;">'.date("Y-m-d h:i A", strtotime($carReport1['Datefrom']))." ".date("Y-m-d h:i A", strtotime($carReport1['DateTo']))." ".$carReport1['Price']." ".$carReport1['PriceTaken']." ".$carReport1['CarName']." ".$carReport1['CarModel']." ".$carReport1['CarNumber']." ".$carReport1['CarColor']." ".'</div>';
                //echo $carReport1['Price'] - $carReport1['PriceTaken']; //Edit here later
                $totalprice += $carReport1['Price']-$carReport1['PriceTaken']-$carReport1['PricePaid']; //تم اضافة المصروفات ضمن القيم المطروحة
                //echo '<br/>';//******   Edit here later *******

                ////// تمت عملية حساب اذا كان لديه رصيد ام لا ///////
                $totalprice_paid += $carReport1['PricePaid']+$carReport1['PriceTaken']-$carReport1['Price'];
            }
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $totalprice > 0){
                /// تمت اضافة قيمة PricePaid ضمن العملية الحسابية
                echo "مدين بــ ".$totalprice." ج.م";
                echo '<br/>';
            }
            //
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $totalprice_paid > 0){
                /// تمت اضافة قيمة PricePaid ضمن العملية الحسابية
                echo "رصيده ".$totalprice_paid." ج.م";
            }
            ////////////////
            ////////////////
            $qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `reports` r1 INNER JOIN `cars` c1 ON r1.CarCode = c1.Car_ID INNER JOIN `driversuser` d1 ON r1.DriverCode = d1.Driver_ID WHERE Datefrom BETWEEN '$date_val' AND '$dateto_val' AND DriverCode = '$selected_val' ORDER BY r1.Datefrom");
            $total_page = ceil (($qry->num_rows/$num_rec_per_page));
            echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
            for($i=1;$i<=$total_page;$i++)
            {
                echo "<li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pg=".$i."'>".$i."</a>"."</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";

            ///////////////
            ///////////////
            echo '</div>';
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**and my DB** :  testing.sql

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.5
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Feb 27, 2019 at 09:33 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.36-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.2.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `testing`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cars`
--

CREATE TABLE `cars` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CarName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `CarModel` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `CarNumber` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `CarColor` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Car_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `cars`
--

INSERT INTO `cars` (`ID`, `CarName`, `CarModel`, `CarNumber`, `CarColor`, `Car_ID`) VALUES
(1, 'تويوتا', 'ياريس', 'ف ق 127', 'ابيض', 'C52134764I'),
(2, 'تويوتا', 'كورولا', 'ط غ 165', 'اسود', 'C27692315I'),
(3, 'جيلي', 'ام جراند', 'ص ل 396', 'ازرق', 'C98050930C'),
(4, 'بي واي دي', 'اف 3', 'س ص 648', 'ابيض', 'C42897410K'),
(5, 'شيفروليه', 'لانوس', 'و د 492', 'فيراني', 'C23439035T'),
(6, 'شيفروليه', 'افيو', 'م ل 345', 'احمر', 'C89045285S');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `driversuser`
--

CREATE TABLE `driversuser` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DriverName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Office` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Company` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `UberMail` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `UberPassword` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `UberPhone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `CareemMail` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CareemPassword` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CareemPhone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Driver_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `driversuser`
--

INSERT INTO `driversuser` (`ID`, `DriverName`, `Office`, `Company`, `UberMail`, `UberPassword`, `UberPhone`, `CareemMail`, `CareemPassword`, `CareemPhone`, `Driver_ID`) VALUES
(1, 'احمد محمد السيد', 'فيوتشر كار', 'Uber', 'example@exm.com', '0155gddd999', '01112345678', '', '', '', 'D15427214J'),
(2, 'محمد علي عوضين', 'فيوتشر كار', 'Careem', '', '', '', 'MohaCM@hotmail.com', 'CM963258', '01235469878', 'D90655118M');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `reports`
--

CREATE TABLE `reports` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DriverCode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CarCode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PriceTaken` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PricePaid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Datefrom` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DateTo` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `reports`
--

INSERT INTO `reports` (`ID`, `DriverCode`, `CarCode`, `Price`, `PriceTaken`, `PricePaid`, `Datefrom`, `DateTo`) VALUES
(1, 'D15427214J', 'C89045285S', 250, 150, 0, '2019-02-23 06:00:00', '2019-02-24 06:00:00'),
(2, 'D15427214J', 'C98050930C', 250, 250, 0, '2019-02-24 06:00:00', '2019-02-25 06:00:00'),
(3, 'D15427214J', 'C23439035T', 250, 100, 0, '2019-02-25 18:00:00', '2019-02-26 18:00:00'),
(4, 'D15427214J', 'C98050930C', 150, 150, 0, '2019-02-26 06:00:00', '2019-02-26 16:00:00'),
(5, 'D15427214J', 'C52134764I', 150, 100, 50, '2019-02-24 06:00:00', '2019-02-24 16:00:00'),
(6, 'D90655118M', 'C42897410K', 150, 50, 100, '2019-02-24 06:00:00', '2019-02-25 06:00:00'),
(7, 'D90655118M', 'C98050930C', 150, 100, 50, '2019-02-01 06:00:00', '2019-02-01 16:00:00');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `cars`
--
ALTER TABLE `cars`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `driversuser`
--
ALTER TABLE `driversuser`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `reports`
--
ALTER TABLE `reports`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `cars`
--
ALTER TABLE `cars`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `driversuser`
--
ALTER TABLE `driversuser`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `reports`
--
ALTER TABLE `reports`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: pagination with only 7 items?

Comment: no it's 8 item there 1 item i still didn't show it yet but i make'd it's show in total result for $totalprice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i founded way to fix that i changed method from POST  to GET and changed $_POST to $_REQUEST and make'd  some change in code blow

```html
<?php

        $divcon = '<div class="result-info" style="text-align: right; font-size: 17px; background-color: #ff661a; padding: 5px; margin-top: 5px;">';
        $num_rec_per_page = 3;
        //if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['DN']) && isset($_REQUEST['DF']) && isset($_REQUEST['DT'])){

            $selected_val = $_REQUEST['DN'];
            $date_val = $_REQUEST['DF'];
            $dateto_val = $_REQUEST['DT'];
            $totalprice = 0;
            $totalprice_paid = 0;
            ////////////////////

            if(isset($_GET['pg']))
            {
                $pg = $_GET['pg'];

            }
            else
            {
                $pg = 1;
            };
            $startfrom = ( $pg-1 ) * $num_rec_per_page;

            ////////////////////
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            $driverName = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `reports` r1 INNER JOIN `driversuser` d1 ON r1.DriverCode = d1.Driver_ID WHERE r1.DriverCode = '$selected_val'");

            while ($datareport2 = mysqli_fetch_array($driverName)) {
                echo $divcon;
                echo "<div style='margin-top: 0px';>";
                echo "<div style='font-size: 18px; color: blue; display: inline';>اسم السائق: </div>";
                echo "<div style='display: inline';>".$datareport2['DriverName']."</div>";
                echo "<div style='display: inline; margin-right: 10%; color: white; border: dotted 2px yellow; padding: 2px;'>";
                echo "<div class='datefrom' style='display: inline; color: white;'>"."فاتوره من ";
                echo "<div style='display: inline; color: black; margin-right: 10px;'>".$date_val."</div>"."</div>";
                echo "<div class='dateto' style='display: inline; margin-right: 10px; color: white;'>"." الي ";
                echo "<div style='display: inline; color: black; margin-right: 10px;'>".$dateto_val."</div>"."</div>";
                echo "</div>"."</div>";
                break 1;
            }
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            /////////***********///////////                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               LIMIT $startfrom , $num_rec_per_page
            $carinfo = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `reports` r1 INNER JOIN `cars` c1 ON r1.CarCode = c1.Car_ID INNER JOIN `driversuser` d1 ON r1.DriverCode = d1.Driver_ID WHERE r1.Datefrom BETWEEN '$date_val' AND '$dateto_val' AND DriverCode = '$selected_val' ORDER BY r1.Datefrom DESC LIMIT $startfrom , $num_rec_per_page");
            while ($carReport1 = mysqli_fetch_array($carinfo)) {

                echo '<div class="reportsrow" style="background-color: #006600; color: white; margin: 7px; padding-right: 8px;">'.date("Y-m-d h:i A", strtotime($carReport1['Datefrom']))." ".date("Y-m-d h:i A", strtotime($carReport1['DateTo']))." ".$carReport1['Price']." ".$carReport1['PriceTaken']." ".$carReport1['CarName']." ".$carReport1['CarModel']." ".$carReport1['CarNumber']." ".$carReport1['CarColor']." ".'</div>';
                //echo $carReport1['Price'] - $carReport1['PriceTaken']; //Edit here later
                $totalprice += $carReport1['Price']-$carReport1['PriceTaken']-$carReport1['PricePaid']; //تم اضافة المصروفات ضمن القيم المطروحة
                //echo '<br/>';//******   Edit here later *******

                ////// تمت عملية حساب اذا كان لديه رصيد ام لا ///////
                $totalprice_paid += $carReport1['PricePaid']+$carReport1['PriceTaken']-$carReport1['Price'];
            }
            if ($totalprice > 0){
                /// تمت اضافة قيمة PricePaid ضمن العملية الحسابية
                echo "مدين بــ ".$totalprice." ج.م";
                echo '<br/>';
            }
            //
            if ($totalprice_paid > 0){
                /// تمت اضافة قيمة PricePaid ضمن العملية الحسابية
                echo "رصيده ".$totalprice_paid." ج.م";
                echo '<br/>';
            }
            ////////////////
            ////////////////
            $qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `reports` r1 INNER JOIN `cars` c1 ON r1.CarCode = c1.Car_ID INNER JOIN `driversuser` d1 ON r1.DriverCode = d1.Driver_ID WHERE Datefrom BETWEEN '$date_val' AND '$dateto_val' AND DriverCode = '$selected_val' ORDER BY r1.Datefrom DESC");
            $total_page = ceil (($qry->num_rows/$num_rec_per_page));
            echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
            for($i=1;$i<=$total_page;$i++)
            {
                //echo "<li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pg=".$i."'>".$i."</a>"."</li>";
                echo "<li><a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?pg=$i&DN=$selected_val&DF=$date_val&DT=$dateto_val\">$i</a></li>";

            }
            echo "</ul>";

            ///////////////
            ///////////////
            echo '</div>';
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
        ?>
```

i founded only 1 post in this site help me with this idea And I'm not satisfied with the whole result and i hope there a way to make it by $_POST

Thanks for all who help me <3